# Getting the width when loading and resizing the page

Tags: jquery, function, resize

i want get width in loading page in a variable and when page was resizing, take width in same variable that i have defined.
Any code I write does not answer
I want to implement this code with the jquery language

Comment: Show us the code you already wrote :)

Answer (score 0):

Link http://api.jquery.com/width/

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();

// Returns width of HTML document
$( document ).width();
```

Comment: no no

i want have define Only one variable in code for window width..then if window was resized, get me the width in same variable.. like call by reference in coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I find this answeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrr

everybody can use it::::

```
<span class="output"></span>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var window_width;
var call;
function get_width(window_width){
    window_width = $(window).width();
    return window_width;
};
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        call = get_width();
        console.log("on resize: "+call);
        $('.output').text(call);
    });
    call = get_width();
    console.log("on load: "+call);
    // show output
    $('.output').text(call);
});


</script>
```